# Sentry doesn't show HttpContext User info in ASP.NET Core application

Tags: asp.net-core, sentry

I've only used the base Sentry configuration from the webPage.

```
  "Sentry": {
    "Dsn": "",
    "IncludeRequestPayload": true,
    "SendDefaultPii": true,
    "MinimumBreadcrumbLevel": "Debug",
    "MinimumEventLevel": "Warning",
    "AttachStackTrace": true,
    "Debug": true,
    "DiagnosticsLevel": "Error"
  }
```

From what I've gathered I should see User info which Setry picks up using its middleware from HttpContext.User.

But on the webPage I only see Ip ::1

[image]

Should I configure something else ? I can't seem to find any extra configuration.

**EDIT**

I'm using Sentry version 1.2.0. My HttpContext.

User is set for sure with user information.

[image]

For Authentication I'm using Jwt Tokens

```
services.AddAuthentication(options => { options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme; })
```

Regards

Comment: well, you don't have a user quite possibly and ::1 it't your local ip

Comment: What version of Sentry.AspNetCore are you using?

Comment: @SilentTremor User is set. I've edited my answer with more information

Answer (score 0):

The [latest release (version 1.2.0, from 8 days ago)](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-dotnet/releases/tag/1.2.0) includes a bug fix where the user when set manually by the application was not reported correctly.

In any case, a user existing in the request should be automatically reported by reading the `ClaimsPrincipal`. This can be changed by adding your own implementation of [IUserFactory](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-dotnet/blob/582d088f10fb1b38d67d3489dcc90799f3741a22/src/Sentry.AspNetCore/IUserFactory.cs#L16) to the container which allows you to create a `User` object by inspecting the `HttpContext`.

In case you are on version 1.2.0 and still have problems, please raise an issue in the GitHub repository for the Sentry .NET SDK:

https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-dotnet/issues/new

Comment: I'm using version 1.2.0. I will raise an issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember what version I used on one of the projects I worked, and I don't remember exactly from where "User" was detected, but if I remember correct was ControllerBase.User

Anyway, depends what authorization mechanism you got, maybe you need to inject it HttpContext.User into ControllerBase.User (typeof ClaimsPrincipal)

On your serviceCollection (startup I guess) do this:

```
services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
services.AddTransient<IPrincipal>(provider => provider.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>().HttpContext?.User);
```

Comment: I checked ControllerBase.User value and it's the same one as in HttpContext.User. Still I've tried your code sample but no help.